# Not able to record the Script using Jmeter getting below mentioned error message

Tags: jmeter

[image]

Not able to record the script using Jmeter ,getting below mentioned error message.

Comment: Hi Vinayak, welcome to SQA. There's not much we can do with a screenshot - are you able to paste the code in to your question please?. Also, what have you tried already to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that JMeter is not able to resolve `http://newtours.demoaut.com/` address, the reasons could be in:

1. Your machine is not connected to the Internet. If this is the case - contact your network administrator or try recording local [intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) resources
2. Your machine is accessing the Internet via corporate proxy. If this is the case you need to configure JMeter to use the same proxy server as your operating system uses to go to the Internet. This can be done in 2 ways:

   - via command-line arguments like

     ```
     jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
     ```
   - via *system.properties* file like:

     ```
     http.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
     http.proxyPort=8000
     https.proxyHost=my.proxy.server
     https.proxyPort=8000
     ```

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the changes up

   More information:

   - [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
   - [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
3. Internet Explorer proxy settings are integrated with Windows Proxy settings so it might be the case you cut yourself from the Internet by modifying Internet Explorer proxy settings for recording. You can try restoring Internet Explorer proxy settings and use a browser with "independent" proxy configuration like [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) for recording.

Answer (score 0):

Try this chrome extension for recording the scripts.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi

This is a free extension provided by blazemeter. You can record and download the recorded file in .jmx format. Then import the file in Jmeter.